# Resources for getting started with MCML?

Tags: .net, media, center, vmc, mcml

Can anyone suggest some references or other resources that are useful in learning MCML?

I have a small pet project I have been working on for a while using C# and .Net 3.5. I have reached a point where I want to be able to send output from it to Windows Media Center, but I have been having a hard time finding coherent explanations of how to create MCML elements to represent my C# data objects.  Particularly I am having  a hard time finding information on creating an MCML element for each element in a C# collection.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Media Center Sandbox](http://blog.mediacentersandbox.com/) is probably the best resource. But I guess you knew that already. The [media center development blog](http://mediacenterdev.blogspot.com/) is also pretty nice. Can [this article](http://mediacenterdev.blogspot.com/2007/02/thinking-and-transferring-data-in-mcml.html) get you started?

I'm very much a n00b myself though..

Answer (score 1):

In addition to keeping up with [sandbox](http://discuss.mediacentersandbox.com/). I would recommend the following.

1. Look at the [Media Center SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A43EA0B7-B85F-4612-AA08-3BF128C5873E&displaylang=en), the Z application and the MCML sampler are a good start.
2. Look at some of the open source MCML application like [VideoBrowser](http://code.google.com/p/videobrowser/), [OML](http://code.google.com/p/open-media-library/), [MusicBrowser](http://code.google.com/p/music-browser/) or [Vmc Netflix](http://code.google.com/p/vmcnetflix/) , read the source, try to figure out how they work.

Ideally, I would recommend trying to join an existing project when it comes to learning MCML, since MCML is really hard to get your head around and has a really steep learning curve. Forget about expression blend, when developing in MCML you are pushing XML files in Visual Studio and dealing with a complex, incomplete and buggy framework.

With your issue, you really need to understand data binding, the open source projects and the sample apps all have examples on how this is done.